# HTML Range input increase/decrease value problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have these three elements in my HTML:

```
<button id="left" >Föregående</button>
<input id="animSlider" type="range" min="0" max="0" step="1" value="0" /> //THE MAX VALUE IS SET DYNAMICLY ON PAGE LOAD, I.E. NOT ZERO
<button id="right">Nästkommande</button>
```

Controlling the value of the input slider is these two listeners/handlers in jquery:

```
$('#left').click( function () {
document.getElementById("animSlider").value -= 1;
});

$('#right').click( function () {
document.getElementById("animSlider").value += 1; 
});
```

For some reason the handler for "previous" (`#left`) works fine, it decreases the value by one. But, the "next" (`#right`) handler, the value increases like this: 1,2, middle of slider, end of slider. I know, there might be some conflict in my code, that I didn't post but I have checked and can't find any connection. The only place where the value is involved, is in these two handlers!

So my question is: **Is there something I'm missing in handling range input values?** Is it the +=/-= that differs in JavaScript? Is there a conflict in using jQuery together with JavaScript in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/my52o1xo/)

Value is a `String`. Convert it to a number.otherwise it increase as 
`0,01,011 ...` instead of `0,1,2..` .However `-` minus automatically convert strings in to numbers because `string - string` doesn't make sense. That's why only previous button is working.`Number(string);` covert string to a number.you can also use `parseInt(string)`

```
$('#right').click(function() {
  document.getElementById("animSlider").value = Number(document.getElementById("animSlider").value)+1;
});
```

Comment: Fast snail, thanks! I assumed it was something wrong with that part, and I dont know how i couldnt find it on my own! Thanks again!

Comment: @MarcusKarlsson my pleasure